# Output of the "ps w" command

Tags: linux, openwrt, ps, daemon

I am using customized OpenWRT, in which no option works for the `ps` command except `w`.

When I enter `ps w`, it’s showing all the running processes, but if I type, for example, `ps w | grep kkkk` it’s showing an output `4414 (username)  1032 R    grep kkkk`.

Obviously this process doesn't exist.

Can anybody please explain this?

Actually, I wanted to get the list of daemon processes running in OpenWRT.

Comment: [`grep` invading my `ps`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/176749/108618).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ps command and grep](https://superuser.com/questions/1151769/ps-command-and-grep)

Answer (score 5):

It is showing you the `grep kkkk` process *that you are running!*

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but maybe someone needs this.
u can install procps-ng-ps

> opkg update && opkg install procps-ng-ps

> ps -l